# No query executing on a table in postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table in PostgreSql-9.4 database called `orders_order`. 
I am unable to run any kind of query on it. No matter what query I run on this table (for eg. `SELECT count(*) from orders_order;` or even `\d orders_order`), nothing happens, except cursor blinking on terminal.

What could have caused it? <strike>And How can I fix it?</strike>

I was running some raw sql queries (`INSERT INTO` queries) using a script in `Django/Python` in a transaction. I abruptly quit the script by pressing `Ctrl + Z`. Since then I am facing this problem

Comment: You could have a running process holding lock on the table (as in `LOCK TABLE orders_order`). Especially as you did **NOT** quit the script. `Ctrl-Z` suspends the running program, but does not quit it.

Comment: @spectras: I doubt `with transaction.atomic():` context manager tries to obtain lock on a table.. but, I am checking for any running process

Comment: it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not terminating your query with a semicolon ;-)

Note that by default the PostgreSQL prompt has three pieces:

```
[dbname][linestatus][is_superuser]
```

for example logged in as Postgres, new line, db is postgres:

```
postgres=#
```

Logged in to db test as non-superuser, new line:

```
test=>
```

Now that = is an important character.  If you have an open paren, it will show:
    test(>

If you are at the top level it will be

```
test->
```

Comment: yup, I actually forgot a semi-colon

Comment: It's fairly common to make that mistake, actually.